# Simple calculator program in C

Tags: c, calculator

I need to write a simple program in C that makes simple calculations of: +,-,*,/

Now, I am using Visual Studio Express 2013, and here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    double a, b;
    double sum = 0;
    char o; //operator

    printf("Enter operator\n");
    scanf_s("%c", &o);
    printf("Enter first operand\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter second operand\n");
    scanf_s("%f", &b);


    if (o == '+'){
        sum = a + b;
        printf("The result is", &sum);
    }

    if (o == '-'){

        sum = a - b;
        printf("The result is", sum);

    }

    if (o == '*'){

        sum = a*b;
        printf("The result is", sum);

    }

    if (o == '/'){

        if (b == !0){

            sum = a / b;
            printf("The result is", sum);
        }
        else printf("Error");
    }
getchar();

    }
```

My output: Enter operator
+ 
Enter first operand
3.5
Enter second operand
5.4

And after I type the second number- the program exits, and nothing!
There are no compilation errors, and I have no idea what to do. Can someone help, please?

Comment: I assume you don't mean printf("The result is", &sum); ;-) (&sum will be the address of the answer, not the answer itself)

Comment: Also, `if (b == !0)` should probably be `if (b != 0)`

Comment: Correct, I meant that sum is the address of the result, but still it's not working

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `printf` correctly. This is what you're using.

```
printf("The result is", &sum);
```

You're not specifying the type of output in the format string, and you're passing the address of the variable you want to print, not the value.

You should use:

```
printf("The result is %lf\n", sum);
```

`%lf` is specifying that you want to print a `double`, `\n` adds a newline, and you pass the value of the variable `sum`, not it's address.

Also, you should change `if (b == !0){` to `if (b != 0){`. If you leave what you put, it's the equivalent to `if (b == 1){`, which probably isn't what you want.

**EDIT** Here is the code, with my modifications, which gives correct results. I'll indicate which lines I changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    double a, b;
    double sum = 0;
    char o; //operator

    /* I had to use scanf, since I'm not using MS/Visual Studio, but GCC */
    printf("Enter operator\n");
    scanf("%c", &o);
    printf("Enter first operand\n");
    scanf("%lf", &a); /* changed %f to %lf */
    printf("Enter second operand\n");
    scanf("%lf", &b); /* changed %f to %lf */

    /* I prefer to use if ... else if ..., this is personal preference */
    if (o == '+'){
        sum = a + b;
        printf("The result is %lf\n", sum); /* Changed, see original post */
    } else if (o == '-'){
        sum = a - b;
        printf("The result is %lf\n", sum); /* Changed, see original post */
    } else if (o == '*'){
        sum = a*b;
        printf("The result is %lf\n", sum); /* Changed, see original post */
    } else if (o == '/'){
        if (b != 0){
        sum = a / b;
            printf("The result is %lf\n", sum); /* Changed, see original post */
        }
        else printf("Error");
    }

    getchar();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @user2309261 I've edited to add more info. Check to see if it helps.

Comment: I tried adding the while (getchar != '\n') ; and what it did was getting stuck after entering the two numbers.. and it won't continue

Comment: @user2309261 I've added in my code, which runs and gives correct values. Take a look and see if there's something in my code that differs to yours.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using `%f` format to read doubles. You should use `%lf`:
   `scanf_s("%lf", &a);`
2. The print methods actually don't print the result (format is incomplete). And, instead of the value, you are passing variable's address. It should be:
   `printf("The result is %e", sum);`
3. You should also change `if (b == !0)` to `if (b != 0)`

Comment: After doing this, the error I got was:Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

Now it's working fine I made some changes to it

the problem was with ur "scanf_s" and "%f" go throw with it

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

    double a, b;
    double sum = 0;
    char o; //operator

    printf("Enter operator\n");
    scanf("%c", &o);
    printf("Enter first operand\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter second operand\n");
    scanf("%d", &b);


    if (o == '+'){
        sum = a + b;
        printf(" The result is %d", sum);
    }

    if (o == '-'){

        sum = a - b;
        printf("The result is %d", sum);

    }

    if (o == '*'){

        sum = a*b;
        printf("The result is %d", sum);
 }

    if (o == '/'){

        if (b == !0){

            sum = a / b;
            printf("The result is %d", sum);
        }
        else printf("Error");
    }
getchar();

    }
```

Comment: The code you have given may ***appear*** to be working but it is not good! Using the `%d` format specifier for a `double` argument is just plain wrong!